# Calculations to constraint a value with only min and max functions

Tags: special-functions

I have an X value that can go from 0.0000001 to infinite.
I want, if this value is less than 0.8, get 0.8
And if that value is equal to or more than 0.8, get 0

How would you do that using only min and max functions (and of course basic +-/x operations) ?

I ask this because I have to calculate this inside a custom piece of software that does not accept/interpret the IF statement, and for the purpose of the asked problem, supports MIN and MAX functions.

Comment: this looks like a homework assignment, is it?

Comment: @ThijsSteel: no, just a headache since hours I'm searching how to do that

Comment: How about combining the theta function and writing the absolute value in terms of min and max?

Comment: If it's not a homework, it's easy to do it like this: `if X < 0.8: return 0.8 else: return 0` and I don't see why you're searching for a supposed to be "more elegant way" to this with only `min` and `max` functions.

Comment: Or, put more directly: what is your reason to use only min and max? People who ask questions like this one often have a problem that can be solved in a better way if they specify a little more about their true task at hand (see "XY problem").

Comment: @AloneProgrammer: It's because I have to use it with a custom piece of software that does not accept/interpret the IF statement, and for the purpose of the asked problem, supports MIN and MAX functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kind of an answer, but it might not be useful depending on what you want to use it for.

Let $t$ be some large parameter, $\text{min}(\text{max}(t*(0.8-x),0),0.8)$ will approximate the function you seek very well. It will only be incorrect for values that are very close to $0.8$, and we can make the approximation arbitrarily accurate by increasing t.

Comment: I like this ! May I ask how you would write this to give x if x>=0.8 and 0.8 if x<0.8 ?

Comment: that's just max(0.8,x)

Comment: Yes, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

The trick is noticing that $|x| = \max(x, 0) - \min(x,0)$. With that, it's easy to get to the function you asked for,
$$f(x) = \mbox{0.4}\left(1-\dfrac{x-0.8}{\max(x-0.8,0)-\min(x-0.8,0)}\right)$$

Comment: Great and smart ! But, if I use anything lower than 0.8, it's ok, but if I use anything greater or equal than 0.8, this formula leads to a division error : f(x)=0.8/2*(1-(calc/calc)) = 0.8/2*0 = 0.8/0. Do you see what's missing in the formula ?

Comment: I edited the formula; the formatting was a bit unclear. The term in parenthesis is not in the denominator. For $x=0.8$ you do get 0/0, but you didn’t specify what the value should be in that case.

Comment: Right, I update the question. If x=0.8, the value should be 0